# Autofocus when using quasar q-field validation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm setting up a form with quasar and use the internal validation. I have a group of checkboxes. The user should select at least one of them. I've managed the validation on form submit, but the only thing that is annoying me: if the validation fails (aka the user didn't select any checkbox), then there is no focus on that field as it is the case for all other fields I use the internal validation for. I guess it has something to do with me using a q-field (instead of q-input).

Here is my code:

```
<q-field v-model="selectedFruits"
         class="q-gutter-sm"
         :rules="[ val => val.length >= 1 || 'Select at least one fruit']"
         :disable="isReadOnly()">
                <q-checkbox v-model="selectedFruits" val="Apple" label="Apple"/>
                <q-checkbox v-model="selectedFruits" val="Banana" label="Banana"/>
                <q-checkbox v-model="selectedFruits" val="Pear" label="Pear"/>
                <q-checkbox v-model="selectedFruits" val="Peach" label="Peach"/>
</q-field>
```

Does someone has a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I found your code working as I understood you expect it except the binded disabled which I noticed is an error because linked to a method!

I did tests with **quasar@1.15.23** and the last checkbox unchecked **has focus** after showing validation error then click *space* on keyboard becomes checked.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    selectedFruits: []
  }
});
```

```html
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.15.23/dist/quasar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.15.23/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div class="row justify-center">
    <div class="row justify-center">
      <q-field v-model="selectedFruits"
         class="q-gutter-sm"
         :rules="[ val => val.length >= 1 || 'Select at least one fruit']"
         >
                <q-checkbox v-model="selectedFruits" val="Apple" label="Apple"/>
                <q-checkbox v-model="selectedFruits" val="Banana" label="Banana"/>
                <q-checkbox v-model="selectedFruits" val="Pear" label="Pear"/>
                <q-checkbox v-model="selectedFruits" val="Peach" label="Peach"/>
</q-field>
    </div>
  </div>

  
<!--   :disable="isReadOnly()" -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If You use Vue3 (composite API script setup) just call ref in your field and add .focus()

Example:

```
 <template>
    <input type="text" ref="nameRef " v-model="name">
  <button @click="focus" value="Focus">
 </template>
<script setup>
   import {ref} from "vue"
   const name = ref("");
   const nameRef = ref(null);
     const focus = () => {
             nameRef.value.focus();
          }
</script>
```